# Solrnet q parameter issue with compound query

Tags: solr, solrnet

We are using Solrnet to issue a compound query to Solr based on a set of options that the user can select for e.g. phrase, exact phrase. exclusion, proximity, etc. We are creating the individual queries based on the options selected using the SolrQueryByField API and combining the combination using a SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery with the AND operator. But when we submit the query to Solr, the q parameter that gets submitted is having the + sign added accross all the terms:

```
q=(ContentSearch:(roman)+AND+ContentSearch:("test+case")+AND+-ContentSearch:(wine)+AND+(ContentSearch:(A)+OR+ContentSearch:(B))+AND+ContentSearch:("catacombs+wine"~5)+AND+ContentSearch:([10+TO+20]))}
```

The +AND+ or "test+case" or +AND+- or 10+TO+20 is messing up the query parser. Has anybody encountered this before? Is it something to do with the url encoding when solrnet is sending the request to solr?

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/solrnet/browse_thread/thread/fcfce3f33681671c/9b24847d25a2b749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SolrNet 0.4.0 you can set an optional parameter on the SolrQueryByField `Quoted=false` this will stop the default behavior of QueryByField to escape special characters.

Comment: I have done that .... but still it shows the same behaviour. Not sure why it is adding the + to each of the query clauses and even between the query terms.

Comment: Ah, I see. I am not sure why it is adding the + to each of the query clauses. Might be some embedded special character escaping built into SolrNet.

Comment: Based on a previous question on the SolrNet Google Group - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/solrnet/solrmultiplecriteriaquery/solrnet/zXDIRverHOg/gGRpXaps-8kJ You might consider using edismax and let Solr handle things for you.

Comment: As mentionned by Mauricio Scheffer, "+" character is only a space encoded in your url request